# validates_presence_of not working properly...how to debug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

In my Review model, I have the following:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vendor
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :votes  

  validates_presence_of :summary
end
```

I submit a new entry as follows in the URL:

```
vendors/9/reviews/new
```

The new.html.erb contains a form as follows:

```
<%= error_messages_for 'review' %>

<h1>New review for <%= link_to @vendor.name, @vendor%></h1>

<% form_for(@review, :url =>vendor_reviews_path(@vendor.id)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :summary %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :summary, :rows=>'3', :class=>'input_summary' %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :vendor_id, :value => @vendor.id %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit Review' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

When I leave the field for :summary blank, I get an error, not a validation message:

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.name

Extracted source (around line #3):

```
1: <%= error_messages_for 'review' %>
2: 
3: <h1>New review for <%= link_to @vendor.name, @vendor%></h1>
```

I don't understand what is happening, it works if :summary is populated

```
  def new
    @review = Review.new
    @vendor = Vendor.find(params[:vendor_id])
    @review = @vendor.reviews.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @review }
    end
  end

def create
    @review = Review.new(params[:review])

    #@vendor = Vendor.find(params[:vendor_id]) #instantiate the vendor from the URL id -- NOT WOKRING
    #@review = @vendor.reviews.build #build a review with vendor_id -- NOT working
    @review = @current_user.reviews.build params[:review]#build a review with the current_user id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @review.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Review was successfully created.'
        format.html { redirect_to review_path(@review) }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @review, :status => :created, :location => @review }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to new_review_path(@review) }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @review.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

My *guess* is that when it fails it is going to `redirect_to new_review_path(@review)` and so doesn't know the vendor it.  How can I redirect to `vendor/:vendor_id/reviews/new` instead?

Comment: when @review object is not valid (as constructed by .new(params[:review]) method, it will fail at @review.save. At that point you are redirected to your new_review_path, but you need to try to set up the @review object same as in "new" method. Meaning - load @vendor object and patch it into your @review object if ".save" has failed, before redirecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't have @vendor member variable set - but to fix this, it would be more correct to use not @vendor directly, but through your @review variable instance.

If you are creating new review, you already have @review member variable created, and you simply are populating fields in it - so, you need to set the vendor for @review (unless it's optional)... it would be more correct to use @review.vendor.name instead.

(If vendor is optional, then you obviously must catch all vendor.nil? cases.)

Comment: hmmm...vendor is not optional...you mean to use @review.vendor in the form?

Comment: you meant to set @review.vendor within the controller for both new and create? as @review.vendor = @vendor?

Comment: I think the URL it is failing over to is wrong...not sure how to set it so that is goes to vendor/:vendor_id/review/new to display the form upon validation failure?

Answer (score 0):

What code do you have in the `new` and `create` actions in your `ReviewsController`?

I suspect that your new `Review` is failing validation because the `summary` field is blank and then when the form is redisplayed on validation failure, the `@vendor` instance variable is `nil`.

You need to make sure that `@vendor` is assigned a value for both code paths.

Comment: that might be it, although I'm trying to have vendor/:vendor_id/reviews be the path...I've added how my new actions

Comment: I think the URL it is failing over to is wrong...not sure how to set it so that is goes to vendor/:vendor_id/review/new to display the form upon validation failure?

Comment: okay, I am not assigning a value for vendor, but as you can see, I am trying to use restful so that the :vendor_id is in the path...?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `render :action => 'new'` instead of your `redirect_to new_review_path(@review)`. This will keep your error_messages on the @review object. By redirecting you are losing the old object and creating a new one.

As others has said, you also need to make sure you re-populate the @vender variable in your create method before rendering the view.

PS. I like to use the [ardes resources_controller plugin](http://github.com/econsultancy/resources_controller/tree/master)  for bog standard controller actions like these, makes life a lot easier *for me* and it handles nested resources really well.

Comment: Some some reason my link doesn't work correctly? The underscore is being converted once I save the answer, see below:

http://github.com/econsultancy/resources_controller/tree/master

Comment: but how do I keep the restful URL?  To get to the View/New it is using vendor/:vendor_id/review/new...so shouldn't I still have the vendor ID in the URL already?

Comment: Sorry but I'm a little confused as to what you mean? Have you tried the `format.html { render :action => "new" }`. code? 

The resulting URL will still contain /vendors/vendor_id. By rendering you are not actually calling the method 'new'  but just rendering the template, so you will still need to set the @vender variable in your create action. Give it a try and post back the result.